# How do i return two quersets one from SearchForm and other from Q objects in one view

Tags: python, django-views, django-forms

this is my view function as i have a problem to get docks = Docks.objects.filter(Q(dock_1__icontains=query)) to protein.html page.I have two queries one from SearchForm related to Proteins model and other is from Q objects and i want to get both fields pdb_name and dock_1 but i am only getting one pdb_name with its related parameters from Proteins model only but didnot get dock_1 from Docks model.

`class SearchForm(forms.Form): """Search view showing the top results from the main page of the AMPdb tool."""`

```
# query_id = forms.CharField()
pdb_name = forms.CharField()


def create_query(self):
    """the form fields get put into self.cleaned_data, make a new
    PDBQuery object from those fields and return"""
    query = Proteins(name=self.cleaned_data["pdb_name"])
    query.save()
    return query
```

`class SearchView(generic.FormView): """Search view of the AMPdb tool.""" form_class = SearchForm template_name = "abampdb/search.html" success_url = "/"`

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(SearchView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    query = self.request.GET.get('q', '')
    category = self.request.GET.get('category', '')
    
    docks = Docks.objects.filter(Q(dock_1__icontains=query))
    context = {}
    rows = []
    for peptide in itertools.zip_longest(Proteins.objects.all()):
        rows.append({
            'left': peptide,
        })
    context['rows'] = rows

    context['proteins'] = Proteins.objects.all()
    context['dock'] = docks
    context['query'] = query
    context['category'] = category
    
    try:
        context["protein"] = Proteins.objects.get(
            name=self.request.GET.getlist("pdb_name")
        ) 
            
    except Proteins.DoesNotExist:
        context["protein"] = None
    print(context)
    return context
    # return self.render_to_response(context)
    

def form_valid(self, form):
    params = {
        "pdb_name": form.cleaned_data.get('pdb_name'),
        "dock_1": form.cleaned_data.get('dock_1'),
    }
    return HttpResponseRedirect(
        reverse("abampdb:protein")
        + "?"
        + urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
    )
```

`class ProteinDetailView(generic.TemplateView): template_name = "abampdb/protein.html"`

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ProteinDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    pdb_name = self.request.GET.get('pdb_name', None)
    if pdb_name:
        protein = Proteins.objects.get(name=pdb_name)
        context['protein'] = protein
        context['dock'] = Docks.objects.filter(Q(dock_1__icontains=protein.name))
    return context`
```

i have tried to change form_valid method
but i am getting "GET /protein/?pdb_name=Aurein+1.2&dock_1=None HTTP/1.1" 200 17530" dock_=None but i print context in SearchView i am getting both model objects.
I want to get both model objects on protein.html but i am getting one from Proteins objects. I am totally new to django and I don't know what I was doing wrong or what I have to do to make this works, please help!